# Clear an field on an Xpage?

Tags: xpages

On a XPage how can I clear some fields when a certain radio button is pressed?

The fields are on a panel. Outside of that panel are some radio buttons. In the `onChange` of the radio buttons I change the render property of the panel via a `viewScope` variable and a partial refresh of the panel to make it disappear. This works. I just want to be able to also blank out the fields as well, else the values are saved when the users submits!

Comment: If you don't want the values saved, just don't bind them to a field. Right?

Answer (score 11):

The SSJS equivalent of the `modifyField` simple action is the `setValue` method of the document data source; for example:

`currentDocument.setValue("fieldName", null);`

If someone tells you to instead call `getComponent("someId").setValue(null)`... don't. At first glance, that also works, but it's less efficient, fragile, and doesn't work when the target component is in a repeat control but the event component is outside the repeat. Always update the data source directly... any components bound to that data source will automatically pick up any changes you make.

Answer (score 1):

Add an event that will modify the field on onchange event and refresh the area you want to change.

```
<xp:modifyField    
var="document1" 
name="FIELDNAME" 
value="">
</xp:modifyField>
```

Comment: But if you want to prevent a user from saving data in certain fields you would be better off IMHO by disabling or making read only those fields instead. So something like this computed in the readonly property !@Contains(getComponent("COMPONENTID").getValue(),"VALUE") and then on the partial refresh you can refresh the area and it will make that field read only. I think this approach is better from a user standpoint. I have a workflow app where I make everything in certain areas (panels, tables, etc) readonly by the status a document is in. Similar approach.

Comment: don't ask the component, ask the data.

Comment: Hey, every Gallant needs a Goofus. Yes I have read the posts, heard its the bad approach. I need to correct some of my apps... do we call them upvotes here? have one...

Comment: In our defense, all of IBM's tutorials use the `getComponent("id").getValue()` pattern, so it's only really been the past few months that some of us have realized there's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Use client side onChange to run whichever of these dojo's, where the  < **parentID** >  is the id of the container the RadioButton or RadioGroup is within:

```
dojo.query("*[type=radio]:checked",dojo.byId(parentID)).forEach(function(node, index, nodelist){
            node.checked=false;
        });
dojo.query("*[type=checkbox]:checked",dojo.byId(parentID)).forEach(function(node, index, nodelist){
            node.checked=false;
        });
dojo.query("input",parentID).
    forEach(function(node, index, nodelist){
        node.value = "";
    })
//reset(
```